# Get iCloud Document Share link programmatically

Tags: swift, macos

How can I get the share link for a file on iCloud documents in swift?

I want the link which is generated, when I share a file in iCloud documents from finder (share with another person, copy link).

Answer (score 0):

The truth is: at the current point in time, it is not possible to get the iCloud share link with the API apple offers. Maybe in the future.